# Start a RSelenium server within the RStudio

Tags: selenium, rselenium

When I try to start a server in R I see the Warning message:

> checkForServer()
>   startServer()

**Warning message:
running command '"java" -jar "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/RSelenium/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar" -log "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/RSelenium/bin/sellog.txt"' had status 127**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the orthodox answer is, but I solved this by installing the 64-bit version of Java and rebooting my machine.  (I mistakenly had only the 32-bit version installed, even though I have 64-bit R.)